# Mysql field and data type from query

Tags: mysql, sql

to get the field name in mysql I can grab it from `cursor.desription`:

```
>>> self.cursor.description                                  
# (('date', 253, 0, 30, 30, 31, 0), ('name', 253, 0, 768, 768, 0, 0), ('content_type_id', 253, 0, 90, 90, 0, 1), ('release_year', 2, 0, 6, 6, 0, 1))                                   
>>> fields = [item[0] for item in self.cursor.description]
```

Is there a way to get the inferred data type, for example `DATE`, `VARCHAR`, etc. ?

I am guessing it is the second column as all varchars are `253`, but what are all the type codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [description](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-description.html) returns:

```
(column_name,
 type,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 null_ok,
 column_flags)
```

The [less documented codes for the type](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/91a17cedb1ee880fe7915fb14cfd74c04e8d6588/include/field_types.h#L57) and [the easier to read version](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/4869291f7ee258e136ef03f5a50135fe7329ffb9/router/src/mock_server/src/mysql_protocol_common.h)

```
  DECIMAL = 0x00,
  TINY = 0x01,
  SHORT = 0x02,
  LONG = 0x03,
  FLOAT = 0x04,
  DOUBLE = 0x05,
  NULL_ = 0x06,
  TIMESTAMP = 0x07,
  LONGLONG = 0x08,
  INT24 = 0x09,
  DATE = 0x0a,
  TIME = 0x0b,
  DATETIME = 0x0c,
  YEAR = 0x0d,
  NEWDATE = 0x0e,
  VARCHAR = 0x0f,
  BIT = 0x10,
  MYSQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP2 = 0x11, /* added */
  MYSQL_TYPE_JSON = 0xf5, /* added */
  NEWDECIMAL = 0xf6, /* corrected based on harder to read  - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99416 */
  ENUM = 0xf7,
  SET = 0xf8,
  TINY_BLOB = 0xf9,
  MEDIUM_BLOB = 0xfa,
  LONG_BLOB = 0xfb,
  BLOB = 0xfc,
  VAR_STRING = 0xfd,
  STRING = 0xfe,
  GEOMETRY = 0xff
```

update: easier to read version had bug differences - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99416